# crystal reports not releasing connections

Tags: crystal-reports

We are connecting to MySQL using JNDI connection.From java portal we are viewing the reporrs. The.The problem is that every report is holding the connection and it is not releasing after we closed the report. It is is creating new connection for every report.
So due to this there is memory full and my db servers got down. 
Please suggest how to release the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are creating your own connection at runtime via setting the authentication. you have to manually close the connection and call the dispose before disposing the report.

DtAdapter.Dispose()

Con.Close()

Con.Dispose()

rpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear()

rpt.SetDataSource(DataTable)